# mass .js to .coffee conversion using js2coffe and bash

Tags: javascript, bash, coffeescript, converters

I want to convert a pile of .js to .coffee files using the find command like:

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec js2coffee {} \;
```

well this works but instead of writing a file it writes to screen.
how do i force it to write each .js as .coffee instead or whatever?

UPDATE:
Solved. See the solution below.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer or delete the question; it doesn't belong in the question.

Comment: Also why would you want to convert js to coffeescript which will then recompile down to js. It's already in its target language! Have you ever played telephone?

Comment: @tkone: it tends to be done as a starting step, so that you can then work on the codebase in CoffeeScript with at least some of the conversion being automatic rather than manual. Thus, future maintenance/development can take place in CoffeeScript rather than JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan still, you're just asking for trouble. Not only have you abstracted out the original source, but it's just a further abstraction from the end goal (which is the language it already was in). The appropriate measure is to keep it in js and when you have refactor, then convert it by just writing new coffeescript. Our current work project is groovy, java, js and python. We aren't going to convert it all to one language - each has their own strengths

Comment: your `bash` command is not right.

Comment: @kev why? It seems to work as far as I can say.

Comment: @tkone: you are partially right. I do it for 2 reasons: first, I find coffee syntax easier to grasp in many cases, secondly I can work from coffee files further. Can publish them for the others since the js2coffee sin't perefect I have to work it anyway. Coffee is much to learn and temper with. I'm not a coder. I started recently with Js and Cs makes my life easier. I do basic stuff and Js is a major pain with it's wierd scope, global and local variables etc. I learned C in late 90's in early teens. Now with 30+ im more then happy to have Coffe, it works and I can grab a beer earlier.

Comment: @tkone I had to get back to your answer and give you the credit. You were right, I was wrong. In more complex deployment it actually work in the opposite direction and fancy syntax is an illusion. Back to getting JS into that head of mine.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

```
$ext=".coffee"
for filen in $(find . -name '*.js'); do js2coffee $filen > $filen$ext; done
```

problem solved with this simple bash script

Comment: You'll find that a lot of tools on unix can't accept file lists as inputs.  `zip` is another one where you need to do a bash `for` loop

Comment: Whoah... Please test this on a sample dir before you try it - It seemed legit to me but it ended up erasing the content of all my js file and did not create any coffee. Good thing it on backup! Still not clear what happened but its all gone